# Why my twitter bootstrap button component are not coloured with gradient?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Do you guys have an idea why my twitter bootstrap button component are not coloured with gradient? They are coloured, but with a solid colour, different from here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons

Thank you very much!

Edited:

Using the css file straight from here http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css it worked perfeclty. That's strange because i just downloaded the files from http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html and i didn't make any modifications!

Comment: You'll have to post the HTML you're using to declare your button.

Comment: In what browser? Are you working with a modified bootstrap sheet? Post some code so we can take a look.

Comment: @LeandroFaria post your solution in the form of an answer below and approve it to close this thread to help future users.

Comment: @AndresIlich Sure! I'll do it as soon as i can. It says that i need to wait 8 hours because i'm a new user.

Answer (score 3):

For googlers coming here re: Bootstrap 3:

In version 3, they decided that people will find it easier to create themes for bootstrap if the default styles were simple, so, they took off gradients.

However, they have almost the same old look in a default theme they created.

For example, the following gets you the gradient:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
```

This was copied from:
http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download-cdn

To see how this looks, look at the last example in official examples at (http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples), which redirects you to:
http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/

Regarding the decision from them, this is quoted from their official blog post:
http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2013/08/19/bootstrap-3-released/

> New design and an optional theme! With v3, we've gone flat. Don't call
>   it a trend—it's all about customization, folks. Since we simplified
>   the aesthetics though, we thought it'd help to have an optional theme.
>   To use it, check out the Bootstrap theme example.

The post is worth checking for more details and changes in v3.

Answer (score 0):

Using the css file straight from here http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css it worked perfectly. That's weird because i just downloaded the files from http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html and i didn't make any modifications!